# Can a series of promises and then handlers be written in waitOneCycle.then(waitOneCycle().then(...)) but without deep nesting?

Tags: promise, es6-promise

If we already have

```
const waitOneCycle = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve));
};
```

Then our code (this is currently used in Jest and SinonJS although it doesn't have to be:)

```
waitOneCycle()
  .then(() => {
    // do something

  });
```

and it reads really elegantly: the `waitOneCycle` and `then` do something.

However, if we do a series of them, we have to:

```
waitOneCycle()
  .then(() => {
    // do something

    return waitOneCycle();
  })
  .then(() => {
    // do something

    return waitOneCycle();
  })
  .then(() => {
    // do something

    return waitOneCycle();
  });
```

and it reads in a strange way, because why would we return something to act as "waitOneCycle"?  This is the way it works, but the code just read in a strange way.

We could do something like:

```
waitOneCycle()
  .then(() => {

    // not return anything here
  })
  .then(() => {
    waitOneCycle()
      .then(() => {

      });
  })
```

but this would go back to the nesting hell issue in the past. Is there a way to refactor it so it reads coherently but at the same time all actions are serialized?

P.S. in the case of Ruby, if the promises are chained this way, it actually can read out quite well, as we don't need to use `return` for the last value evaluated. So it'd read like `waitOneCycle`, `then`, `waitOneCycle`, `then`... and it appears quite elegantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to nest (and it would only work if you were to `return` the inner promise anyway), you can also chain it:

```
waitOneCycle()
  .then(() => {
    // do something
  })
  .then(waitOneCycle)
  .then(() => {
    // do something
  })
  .then(waitOneCycle)
  .then(() => {
    // do something
  })
  .then(waitOneCycle);
```

This might work even better if you make `waitOneCycle` pass through the value:

```
const waitOneCycle = (v) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, v));
};
```

Of course, if you want promise code that reads coherently and has no nesting (not even that of `then` callbacks), you should just go for `async`/`await` syntax.

Comment: The `.then(waitOneCycle)` way is quite interesting... in a way, we may think the `fn` of `then(fn)` is a handler... and now it is a function that returns a promise, so it fulfills the "a function that returns a promise" and will be used as the promise for the next chained `then()`. So it works elegantly.  I am not sure if this is coincidental, or is it just designed this way to begin with, but it is nice

Comment: you tagged a last `.then(waitOneCycle)` at the very end and doesn't tag any `then()` to it... so it doesn't do anything? Maybe you put it there just for fun or just when copy and pasting you put an extra one there?

Comment: @nonopolarity No, this is not coincidental, this is how promises were designed.

Comment: @nonopolarity The `.then(waitOneCycle)` at the end is because you also had a `return waitOneCycle();` in the last `then` callback of your series. Sure, drop it if you don't need it.

Comment: oh I didn't expect my code rewritten so faithfully... haha